# Group by date intervals using JPA's Criteria API

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to group entities by date intervals using JPA's Criteria API. I use this way of querying for entities as this is a part of the service that serves API requests which may ask for any field of any entity, including sorting, filtering, grouping and aggregations. Everything works fine except for grouping by date fields. My underlying DBMS i PostgreSQL.

To give a minimal example, here's my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "receipts")
public class DbReceipt {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Date sellDate;
    // Many other fields
}
```

This example discusses grouping my "month" interval (therefore grouping by year+month), but in the end I'm looking for a solution that would let me group by any interval, such as "year", "day" or "minutes".

What I'm trying to achieve is the following query, but using Criteria API:

`SELECT TO_CHAR(sell_date, 'YYYY-MM') AS alias1 FROM receipts GROUP BY alias1;`

My attempt to do so is this:

```
@Service
public class ReceiptServiceImpl extends ReceiptService {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void test() {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
        Root<?> root = query.from(DbReceipt.class);
        Expression<?> expr = cb.function("to_char", String.class, root.get("sellDate"), cb.literal("YYYY-MM"));

        query.groupBy(expr);
        query.multiselect(expr);

        TypedQuery<Object[]> typedQuery = em.createQuery(query);
        List<Object[]> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
    }
}
```

The reason I use `to_char` function and not `MONTH` and similar is that I need entities like `2019-05` and `2020-05` to not be grouped together. I also narrow this example down to only year and month to keep things short, but the goal is to group by any date interval.

The code above creates the following query (SQL logging enabled) which results in an error:

```
Hibernate: select to_char(dbreceipt0_.sell_date, ?) as col_0_0_ from receipts dbreceipt0_ group by to_char(dbreceipt0_.sell_date, ?)
24-05-2020 12:16:30.071 [http-nio-1234-exec-5] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42803
24-05-2020 12:16:30.071 [http-nio-1234-exec-5] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - ERROR: column "dbreceipt0_.sell_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 16
```

which to me is caused by the fact that the whole expression is put into the 'group by' part of the query, rather than just an alias. Now, I've tried to assign an alias to the expression (which returns `Selection<T>` and groupBy accepts expressions, therefore I can only really use that in the `multiselect`), but that didn't affect how the query is performed - nothing changed.

How do I achieve grouping by year and month as described above using Criteria API? Maybe there's a different way other than using `to_char`? Maybe there's a way to give an alias to the `groupBy` method that would cause it to group by an alias instead of the whole expression?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug in PostgreSQL (the error comes from there, not from Hibernate). I have tried a slightly modified version of your code with EclipseLink + Derby and works perfectly.
Note that I had to use numbers instead of strings because Derby DB doesn't have an equivalent of `TO_CHAR` function.

```
Expression<Integer> year = cb.function("YEAR", Integer.class, root.get("sellDate"));
Expression<Integer> month = cb.function("MONTH", Integer.class, root.get("sellDate"));
Expression<Integer> expr = cb.sum(month, cb.prod(12, year));
query.groupBy(expr);
query.multiselect(expr);
```

This returns the following SQL:

```
SELECT (MONTH(MY_DATE) + (12 * YEAR(MY_DATE))) 
FROM MY_DATE_TABLE 
GROUP BY (MONTH(MY_DATE) + (12 * YEAR(MY_DATE)))
```

Note that there are no portable solutions for manipulating dates in JPA criteria queries. If the number of groups to be queried simultaneously is not too high I'd go with a more practical approach where you find the dates in Java and pass them as literals to the query builder.

Another workaround is to query with a `groupBy(root.get("sellDate"))` and then aggregate the results in Java according to the desired time period.

Post Scriptum: I don't think it's relevant, however I modified the query's return type from `Object[]` to `Object`.

Comment: While this works specifically for year and month, my general problem is that I need to support all date intervals, not just year+month as in the question. I don't sadly see how to apply this approach for "day" - and therefore also all more granular intervals - due to months having different number of days and also due to leap years - there's no single value I'd be able to put inside the "product" function to multiply the result of "DAY" function by. I like your approach for year+month case, but it seems not universal enough for my more general case.

Comment: Edited question to explain what I'm trying to achieve in more detail

Comment: @JacekŚlimok I think you didn't get my point. I do think that your approach works perfectly if you switch to EclipseLink as JPA provider. I used the integer approach simply because I am using a different DB. I'll try later with Hibernate

Comment: Oh okay, now I get it. This is interesting though, as your code works in my case, whereas the original `TO_CHAR` version does not. I've posted this on hibternate's bugtracker, we'll see what happens: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14045

Comment: @JacekŚlimok note that the difference between the two is the `?` part. Looking at the compiled query, it is evident Hibernate created parameters for both `'YYYY-MM'` strings instead of actually treating them as literals. I'd wager in your scenario, Postgres simply doesn't recognize the `?` from `SELECT` and the `?` from `GROUP BY` to be the same value, hence the error

Comment: @crizzis May be true, but even in this case I'm trying to figure out a solution or workaround to my original problem

Comment: Unfortunately there are no portable solutions for manipulating dates in JPA criteria queries. If the number of groups to be queried simultaneously is not too high I'd go with a more practical approach where you find the dates in Java and pass them as literals to the query builder

Comment: In my case, the number of groups to be queried is unknown in advance and - considering the 'seconds' date interval may be specified in API, which is highest possible granularity - it may result in number of groups about equal the total number of entries in the database. I do however place an upper limit on the number of query results returned in a single query using `setMaxResults`. Again, the end goal is to support this flexible API which allows the user to request grouping by date with any interval, so it's not up to me to decide upfront. I'm just trying to find any possible solution.

Comment: @JacekŚlimok the simplest workaround would be to [register a custom function](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-sql-function-jpql-criteria-api-query/) for the entire `TO_CHAR(?, 'YYYY-MM')` expression. You would need a separate function for each format string, though